# TFS missing work item type Change Request

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs-power-tools

I have just started at a new company and have been making some improvements to their existing Team Foundation Server 2010.  But for some reason when I use the power tools to Select a work item type there is no Change Request work item. And you can't select this type from the new work item menu.  It's like someone has deleted that type from the server.  Is there any way I can get this type back or somewhere on the web I can get the xml to import the type back in using the power tools?

**TFS version is 2010**

Thanks for help in advance,

Comment: What process template are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It may have been made with a different template than you are used to.

You'll want to [download a project template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181511%28VS.80%29.aspx) that has the change request type ([CMMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332482.aspx)). Then use [witadmin to import the work type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404856.aspx)